# Flask template_folder paramter not being used

Tags: python, flask

I have a `Flask` app using blueprints and I was wanting to change the directory in which the blueprints searched for templates.

I have created a blueprint as follows:

```
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='newName')

@main.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template("index.html")
```

I then register and run my app:

```
app.register_blueprint(main)
app.run(debug=True)
```

however, if I then go and change the name of my `templates` directory to `newName` I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound`. If I change the directory name back to `templates`, my app works fine and renders the `index.html` page; the blueprint is being registered fine but the `template_folder` param seems to be inconsequential. Why is it not having an affect and how do I store my templates in `newName` using blueprints?

EDIT:

I have the following structure:

```
run.py <--- from app import build
            build().run(debug=True)
app/
    __init__.py <--- define build: register bp and return app
    controllers/
        __init__.py <--- import main blueprint from main
        main.py <--- create main blueprint as above
    newName/
        index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ tree
.
├── app.py
└── foo
    ├── bp
    │   └── index.html
    └── __init__.py

2 directories, 3 files
# atupal at xiaomi in /tmp/atupal/py [13:25:26]
$ cat app.py 
from flask import Flask

import foo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(foo.bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
# atupal at xiaomi in /tmp/atupal/py [13:25:28]
$ cat foo/__init__.py 
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__, template_folder='bp')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')
# atupal at xiaomi in /tmp/atupal/py [13:25:37]
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/
<p>
  index
</p>
```

From the doc, we can see:

> As for static files, the path can be absolute or **relative to the blueprint resource folder**. The template folder is added to the searchpath of templates but with a lower priority than the actual application’s template folder. That way you can easily override templates that a blueprint provides in the actual application.

So if the template_folder you provided is not exist. Flask will search it in application's template folder which default name is "templates".

Comment: The altered name works for me too using that project structure, I updated my question to show my project structure which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you need move the `newName` fold under `controllers`

Comment: Why does it work if I change `newName` to `templates`? Is it flask rolling back to default value or something?

Comment: Because the default template folder name is `templates`